# How can I display data in one table from different sql statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I Just only done first sql statement. Please see the link for demo what i've done till now. [demo](http://prntscr.com/57knmk)

I want to show the other three sql statement's result in the other there columns. Check what i've wanted to do and finally want to do sum of the all time slot value. [demo](http://prntscr.com/57kp87)

As far i've tried below code:

```
            <?php
             $first_time_slot = "00:00:00 - 06:00:00";
             $second_time_slot = "06:01:00 - 12:00:00";
             $third_time_slot = "12:01:00 - 18:00:00";
             $fourth_time_slot = "18:01:00 - 23:59:59";

            $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT date(`calldate`) as date, count(`src`)as total_caller, sum(`duration`) as total_duration FROM `cdr` WHERE time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00' AND `accountcode` = '09614008155' group by date order by date DESC");

            $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT date(`calldate`) as date, count(`src`)as total_caller, sum(`duration`) as total_duration FROM `cdr` WHERE time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '06:01:00' AND '12:00:00' AND `accountcode` = '09614008155' group by date order by date DESC");

            $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT date(`calldate`) as date, count(`src`)as total_caller, sum(`duration`) as total_duration FROM `cdr` WHERE time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '12:01:00' AND '18:00:00' AND `accountcode` = '09614008155' group by date order by date DESC");

            $sql4 = mysql_query("SELECT date(`calldate`) as date, count(`src`)as total_caller, sum(`duration`) as total_duration FROM `cdr` WHERE time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '18:01:00' AND '23:59:59' AND `accountcode` = '09614008155' group by date order by date DESC");
            ?>


        <table border="1" width="90%" class="fancy">
            <caption style="color:#FF0000; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:16px;">Showing Caller History.</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>12am - 6am</th>
                <th>6am - 12pm</th>
                <th>12pm - 6pm</th>
                <th>6pm - 12am</th>
                <th>Total Caller</th>
            </tr>

            <?php if (isset($first_time_slot)){
                while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) { ?>
            <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row1['date']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row1['total_caller']; ?></td>

            <?php }} ?>
            </tr>


        </table>
```

Till now i just apply only 1st sql statement. How can i apply ohter three sql statements for other three columns. Please help me. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If its possible to do using only one query then let me know please..

Comment: Instead of directly creating the output, get your mysql results first and store them in an appropriate array. Only then, create your output from that array. Or just get all the data for all calls in one query and execute the separating logic in PHP.

Comment: @Paul How can i get all the data for all calls in one query and execute the separating logic in PHP? Can you show me some demo fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test but to make thing easier you can keep your code using 4 queries and change your php code like this (it is not the best solution :) ):

```html
<tr>
<?php if (isset($first_time_slot)){
 if ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $row1['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1['total_duration']; ?></td>       
 <?php }

 if ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $row1['total_duration']; ?></td>
 <?php }
 
 if ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $row1['total_duration']; ?></td>
 <?php }
 
 if ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql4)) { ?>
            <td><?php echo $row1['total_duration']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1['total_caller']; ?></td>
 <?php }

} ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested you can use one query like this

```html
SELECT date(`calldate`) as date, count(`src`)as total_caller, sum(`duration`) as total_duration
FROM `cdr`
WHERE  (time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00')
 Or (time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '06:01:00' AND '12:00:00')
 Or (time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '12:01:00' AND '18:00:00')
 Or (time(`calldate`) BETWEEN '18:01:00' AND '23:59:59')
AND `accountcode` = '09614008155' group by date order by date DESC
```

Comment: this is fine but I need different time wise count(`src`) results in different output column please see my output demo http://prntscr.com/57kp87

Comment: your query return this result http://prntscr.com/57kvsy can you make it total_caller in different sql column by the given timewise?

Comment: I just want to count `src` in four time slot with 24 hours formatting. Can you please check my output demo link once more?

Comment: It is difficult to change as columns result. Keep them as rows result and adjust your php code. Make the <tr> outside the while loop nad inside the loop display the column using the rows that you get from this query.

Comment: I couldn't understand how to do that. :(